# Native call vs Java call - time taken to connect serial communication

Tags: java, sockets, serial-port, native

I have written a serial communication code in C and Java for Windows platform. Below is the lines of code. Both the lines check if host is reachable.
The difference of the time taken to connect for C and Java is very huge as shown below:

**Native socket connection call:** takes about **0 milliseconds**

```
connect( sock, (struct sockaddr *)&host_address, sizeof(host_address));
```

**Java socket connection call:** takes about **621 milliseconds**

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(ipAddress, portNumber);
```

Can anyone tell me why there is so much of difference? What I think is Java ends up taking lot of time because of the interaction of byte code with Native code. If this is so, why?

Comment: Is your C code also creating an SSL socket connection, or just a plain socket connection?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: c code also creates SSL socket connection.